# bandpass filter design help

Tags: amplifier, filter

I need help designing a band pass filter that passes frequencies only between 500 and 1000Hz[image] Attached is my filter that i made in multi-sim but for some reason nothing comes up on the oscilloscope. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Power supply is reversed, for a start.

Comment: just changed it and still nothing

Comment: Please edit your question to show the updated circuit.

Comment: Connect your "oscilloscope" to different points in the circuit and verify that the signals look correct, but start at the **input** and work your way to the output. This process is called **debugging** and it is much more productive than staring at the circuit.

Comment: *I need help designing a band pass filter that passes frequencies only between 500 and 1000Hz* - when you find it, you will have uncovered the equivalent of the holy grail.

Comment: nothing comes up: perhaps zero volt dc, or V1?